# Divide multiple columns by another column in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following code that is working on data frame

```
 test %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('1'), starts_with('2')), `/`, quote(Unit))
```

However, I am trying to migrate it to data.table due to the size of `test` in order to gain speed. I started by selecting the columns as:

```
test[, .SD, .SDcols = names(test) %like% "1|2"]
```

but i struggle to design the function to divide by `Unit`. COuld anyone help

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example ? I gave you an answer but I'm not sure this is exactly what you want

Comment: many thanks that's exactly what i needed but testing he does not find 'x'  Error in get("x") : object 'x' not found. Debugging

Comment: Yes that"s normal. In my example the column is named `x`. In yours, you should change the name to the one you want. Probably `Unite`, right ?

Comment: Please let me know if it's what you want. I will edit the answer in consequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example would help. From what I understood in your problem, you want to divide some columns starting with *1* or *2* by some other column.

I show you an example of what can be done

```r
df = data.table(
  "Unite" = 2L,
  "1y" = rnorm(10),
  "2y" = rnorm(10)
)
df
    Unite         1y         2y
 1:     2 -1.4745875  1.1462019
 2:     2 -0.9258819  1.3628202
 3:     2  1.4676818 -0.5624427
 4:     2 -0.2385211 -1.1704368
 5:     2 -0.3172192  0.9186491
 6:     2  1.5307232 -1.7340884
 7:     2  0.5721486 -1.3873970
 8:     2  0.2885397  0.5455075
 9:     2 -0.9102919 -0.6109027
10:     2  0.8080263 -1.1048748
```

What you can do is a combination of `lapply` + `.SD` :

```r
cols <- colnames(df)[grepl("^(1|2)",colnames(df))]
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(d) d/get('Unite')), .SDcols = cols]

 Unite         1y         2y
 1:     2 -0.7372938  0.5731010
 2:     2 -0.4629409  0.6814101
 3:     2  0.7338409 -0.2812214
 4:     2 -0.1192605 -0.5852184
 5:     2 -0.1586096  0.4593246
 6:     2  0.7653616 -0.8670442
 7:     2  0.2860743 -0.6936985
 8:     2  0.1442698  0.2727538
 9:     2 -0.4551459 -0.3054514
10:     2  0.4040131 -0.5524374
```

Answer (score 4):

```
test[ , lapply(.SD, '/', Unit), .SDcols = patterns('^[12]')]
```